# How to do a calculation on keypup, for several rows, one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculated-field

I have a form with several rows. I would like to calculate the totals for each row. i.e. `cost * unit` price and put the result in the total input. Here is the script I tried:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var input;
    $('#p1').keyup(calculate('#p1'));
    $('#p2').keyup(calculate('#p2'));
});
function calculate(input)
{
    $(input + 'Total').val($(input).val() * $(input + 'cost').val());

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one problem is that the [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) method expects a function. The way you use `calculate` in your example, you invoke the function immediately when adding the event.

To avoid this, you could do something like this:

```
$('#p1').keyup(function () { calculate('#p1') });
```

Another option would be to have the calculate function return a function reference:

```
function calculate(input)
{
    return function () {
        $(input + 'Total').val($(input).val() * $(input + 'cost').val());
    }
}
```

You could then add the event-handler as you do today:

```
$('#p1').keyup(calculate('#p1'));
```

Comment: @user2188335 Glad it worked! I notice you have accepted any answer to your previous questions. Here is a little more info on why it is good to mark the most useful answer as the accepted one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Accepted. One last question though. Can we add a sum on this function to sum all input with id #p1total, #p2total, #p3total. I use php loop to generate the 1,2,3..

Comment: @user2188335 Not sure I understand your question. You could add an additional class to your "total"-inputs, that you can use for selection, let's call it `row-total`. You can then use that class to select all row-total inputs, loop over them and add their values together. Is that what you want?

Comment: ok that is a good idea. now that i have all inputs with the class "row-total", some may be empty. is there a way i can check for empty inputs as i loop and sum them?

Comment: @user2188335 Sure, in the loop your could do something like `var value = $(this).val() === "" ? 0 : $(this).val();`. Now the variable `value` will contain 0 if the input is empty, or the value of the input if not empty.

Comment: ok. i encountered another problem: $('.row-total').each (function(){ sum += $(this).val() === "" ? 0 : $(this).val(); }); It does not SUM but it JOINS. i also realized the input value="". that is value is empty BUT i can see the value on browser interface for that input. code for that is $(input + 'Total').val($(input).val() * $(input + 'cost').val()); Which works

Comment: @user2188335 That is probably because `.val()` will return a string. When using `+` on two strings, the behavior is to concatenate the strings. In order to sum the numbers, you will need to parse the strings into numbers first. Have a look at [`parseFloat(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)